# Logistic and Quadratic map

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand the relation between a logistic map and a quadratic map. For example, how can you modify a logistic map for the quadratic map, i.e., modifying the logistic map $x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n)$ to the quadratic $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+c.$

Comment: There are so many twists and turns in the comments of the accepted answer that the following might prove useful: if $(x_n)$ solves $$x_{n+1}=rx_n(1-x_n),$$ then the change of variable $$z_n=\tfrac12r-rx_n,$$ yields the desired quadratic recursion $$z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c,$$ for $$c=\tfrac12r-\tfrac14r^2.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$rx_n(1-x_n)=rx_n-rx_n^2=-(\sqrt{r})^2(x_n-\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{r}{4}$.

Now make the Substitution $(x_n- \frac{1}{2}) \sqrt{r} = y_n$ from which follows $y_{n+1}=(x_{n+1}- \frac{1}{2}) \sqrt{r}$. When you replace $x_n$ by the $y_n$ you will have the quadratic map.

Comment: What do you mean by, "When you replace $x_n$ by the $y_n$ you will have the quadratic map"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: $x_{n+1}=-(\sqrt{r}(x_n- \frac{1}{2}))^2+ \frac{r}{4} = -y_n^2 + \frac{r}{4}$; Moreover: $x_{n+1}= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{y_{n+1}}{\sqrt{r}}$. Combining These results you have: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{y_{n+1}}{\sqrt{r}} = - y_n^2 + \frac{r}{4}$.

Comment: so the quadratic map will then be $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{r}(-y_n^2+\frac{r}{4}-\frac12)$?

Comment: yes; if you want to have the coefficient 1 instead of $- \sqrt{r}$ for the $y_n^2$ term you can rescale $y_n$ by the Substitution: $y_n = - \frac{y_n}{\sqrt{r}}$.

Comment: Actually, this is my last question. For $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+c$, what is $c$ in $y_{n+1} = \sqrt{r}(-y_n^2+\frac{r}{4}-\frac12)?$

Comment: After the Substitution $y_n = -\frac{z_n}{\sqrt{r}}$ it follows: $-\frac{z_{n+1}}{\sqrt{r}} = -\frac{z_n^2}{\sqrt{r}} + \sqrt{r}(\frac{r-2}{4})$. Now multiply by $- \sqrt{r}$.

Comment: Is $c$ usually taken to be a complex number?

Comment: $c$ is an ordinary complex number (real numbers are also (a subset of) complex numbers).